# Visual Studio Code with Java Extension Pack not highlighting errors in Linux

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Java Extension. In windows, I get a highlight of all the errors in the IDE, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

But when I write the same code, with the same errors and with the same extensions in linux, the highlight doesn't work:

[image]

Before you say it, yes the error is there. If a run the code I get the error "Executer". Compared settings and are all the same. Java is detected, the thumb is up.

The version in linux mint and windows is 1.30.1.

Comment: Why do these screenshots show different classes?

Comment: As for the errors in question, you're likely getting different errors; the error in the first screenshot is caused by a missing `import`.  The error in the second screenshot is likely a missing method error because you misspelled [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) (a class with static methods) as [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) (an interface with no static methods)

Comment: Is the same code, different class name. Those are just practice exercises. About the mispell, you are correct. But the problem is the same: Errors in Linux(doesn't matter wich error) are not highlighted, when in windows they are. Corrected the mispell error(now has the same error than windows), and still not highlighted.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue with Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, this is how I solved it:

1. Shift + Ctrl + P
2. Type `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and select it
3. Reload VS Code